# to get particular value out of django array

Tags: python, django

I applied this code to get id out of a table .

```
        getItemid=cursor.execute("Select id from shop_carthistory where order_id =%s",[order.order_number])
    row=cursor.fetchall()
    context = {order_id": row }


{{order_id}} gives => ((37L,),)
```

I need only 37 out of it

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL rather than the ORM? And why are you using `fetchall()` if you only want one result?

Comment: ... and what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tuple with one element that is a tuple with one element:

```
In [35]: a = ((37,),)

In [36]: a
Out[36]: ((37,),)

In [37]: a[0]
Out[37]: (37,)

In [38]: a[0][0]
Out[38]: 37
```